# why comparing empty object directly showing false?

Tags: javascript

I was checking in my console. When i checked empty object directly like `{} == {}` , it show false.

Why it's showing `false` ? shouldn't it show `true` as both are equal ?

Comment: use the more recommended === comparator

Comment: Two separate objects are never equal. But you could do this `var a = {}; var b=a; if(b==a) // will be true`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When i checked empty object directly like {} == {} , it show false.

You have two different objects here and not one. Here `==` checks whether the given two objects are same or not.

Scenario 1:

```
var foo = {}; //new object
var bar = foo; //shared same object
foo == bar;// true
```

Scenario 2:

```
var foo = {}; //new object
var bar = {}; //new object
foo == bar;// false
```

If you still wish to compare two different objects, try this:

```
var foo = {}; //new object
var bar = {}; //new object
JSON.stringify(foo) == JSON.stringify(bar);// true
```

Here, `JSON.stringify({})` gives string value `"{}"`

Answer (score 3):

Both are *NOT* `equal`. Although they are empty, both refers to different objects.

Answer (score 2):

Primitives like strings and numbers are compared by their value, while objects like arrays, dates, and plain objects are compared by their reference. That comparison by reference basically checks to see if the objects given refer to the same location in memory, which they do not, so the comparison is false.